# How to add a image "on" the button at one corner of button?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a image to one corner to a button like this:

[image]

```css
li#menu-item-2046{
  background-color: black;
  margin-inline-end:7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-2046" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2046 item-level-0 menu-item-design-default menu-simple-dropdown item-event-hover">
  <a href="https://www.website.com" class="demo-class">
    <span class="nav-link-text">text</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: What is your question?  what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please provide a working HTML/CSS snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional things to most HTML elements (there are exceptions) using pseudo-elements. These don't actually exist in the DOM but can be used for some nice styling effects, such as your button with an icon.

You would do this by targeting your element in CSS and then appending `::before` or `::after`

It's important to ensure your parent element (your list item in this case) has it's position set, otherwise you'll end up with your pseudo-element halfway across the screen since that's positioned absolutely. As well as ensuring that the z-index is set to which layer you want the image to be on.

```css
ul{
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

ul li{
   position: relative;
   padding: 20px;
   background-color: #444;
   color: #FFF;
   max-width: 250px;
   font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul li#button::after{
    content: url(http://example.com/image.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="button">Example Button</li>
</ul>
```